# Make highgui window stay even after code finishes

Tags: opencv

I am showing an image using the `imshow` function in OpenCV using C++. By default, `imshow` window closes as soon as the execution of the code is complete. I want to know if there is any way to make the highgui window that was opened by the call to `imshow` stay around even after the execution of the code is complete. This means that I want to run `imshow` as a separate task which is independent of the code which created it and close only when I click the close button and not when the execution of the code completes.

Or, is there any way to bind a function to the close button in the window?

Comment: You may see `waitkey()` function http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey and multithreaded application (lib pthread if you're under linux)

Comment: `waitKey()` isn't what I'm looking for. `waitKey()` stops the code from proceeding further.

Comment: I know, it prevents your window to be closed. During this time, another part of your code can be executed in a different thread.

Comment: I want the window to remain even after the entire execution is complete. So this isn't helpful in my problem. But  thanks.

Comment: Why not just save your image, and open it with a preview or something? If the code finishes, there's nothing you can do about it. Either you prevent the code to terminate with a `waitKey()` at the end, or you start another program to show your image

Comment: Is there any way to bind a function to the close button in the window?
Actually, I'm calling `imshow` through Scliab API and even after the code executes, the image window remains open and it hangs. If I could either make the window independent of the code or add a function to the close button, I think it would help.

Comment: old C api has `cvGetWindowHandler`: _"The function cvGetWindowHandle returns native window handle (HWND in case of Win32 and GtkWidget in case of GTK+)."_ You can probably start from that... It seems a lot of work for nothing, though. Just display the image with Scilab

Comment: dont use imshow but use some real gui (instead of the debug gui provided by opencv) to render the images.